# Generating a Xml document from a simple XSD schema

Tags: .net, asp.net, xsd

I have a xsd file and I need to generate a xml file from it. What is the easiest way to achieve this?

EDIT: There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761661/tool-to-generate-xml-file-from-xsd-for-testing) and so i want to close my question. However if you have an answer please post it...

**EDIT:**
One of the [respondents](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67985/demi) deleted their answer, but i found it to be the simplest solution that works for me. It is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302296.aspx)

Comment: +1 for posting a link to the duplicate voluntarily! :-)

Comment: That code (XmlSampleGenerator) is fairly old, and it pulls shenanigans like accessing private, undocumented fields via reflection.  I got it to work on Mono by making a few tweaks, which I'll share if anyone's interested.

Comment: @MatthewFlaschen, can you please share your lessons learned while using XmlSampleGenerator?

Answer (score 1):

It is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302296.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at using [XMLSpy](http://www.altova.com/xml-editor/).  It's a great piece of software..

Answer (score 0):

[Stylus Studio](http://www.stylusstudio.com/index.html) will do this for you by creating an XML with sample data.

File -> Document Wizards -> XML Schema to XML.

But did you want to do this programmatically ?

Comment: Being able to do it programmtically in .NET would be very helpful, but for now i just need an xml file to test deserialization using the xsd.

Comment: Hmmm... I hope the info was useful. Stylus isn't free but has an evaluation version. Personally, I have used a few XML IDE's and found Oxygen XML to be the coolest.