# Any Java "API" to generate Sample XML from XSD?

Tags: java, xml, xsd

As part of our application we need to develop a module that takes in an XSD schema and gives out a sample XML. The XSD schemas will be supplied during runtime. So is there any Java API out there that can do the job?

> Searched this forum and found the following similar questions. But the discussions were around tools to generate sample XML from XSD. Could not find any reference to APIs.
>   [how-to-generate-sample-xml-documents-from-their-dtd-or-xsd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106/how-to-generate-sample-xml-documents-from-their-dtd-or-xsd)
>   [tool-to-generate-xml-file-from-xsd-for-testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761661/tool-to-generate-xml-file-from-xsd-for-testing)
>   [xml-instance-generation-from-xml-schema-xsd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307616/xml-instance-generation-from-xml-schema-xsd)

Comment: try [http://code.google.com/p/jlibs/wiki/XSInstance](http://code.google.com/p/jlibs/wiki/XSInstance)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such API, but it's possible.
'gives out sample XML' means that you will have to implement generation of sample XML node(s) from XSD basic types like `<xs:element name="value" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="0"/>`, taking care of minoccurs/maxoccurs attributes, not storing dates in `xs:integer` nodes, etc, etc..

Once it's done, the rest is not a problem: traversing XSD with `XPath` or `org.w3c.dom.*`, flattening complex types and extensions will do the trick. I bet you'll receive working traversing code here on stackoverflow within minutes after posting question.

Comment: Thank you osw. Will try the approach.

Answer (score 6):

i found java API to generate XML sample from XSD 
 http://code.google.com/p/jlibs/wiki/XSInstance,