# Create XML file according to XSD schema

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I know that there is a lot of such a topics online but the problem is, that none of solutions work for me.
Language I'm using: **Java**
IDE: **Intellij**

Just to make clear, I'm using community edition, maybe that's why none of plugins, like JAXB doesn't work.

From the other file I extracted data (values) and I need to create XML file with this data. Also there is XSD schema here: http://www.bpsim.org/schemas/1.0/

I'm thinking maybe there is any third-party solutions what I can use?
Cause I really don't want to code all the XML file by hands cause it's thousands of values and code.

Anyone knows a good solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any Java "API" to generate Sample XML from XSD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710852/any-java-api-to-generate-sample-xml-from-xsd)

Comment: did you [checked this page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/generating-instance-document-from-xml-schema.html)?

Comment: Yeah, but it's not the same. Let's say, I have a lot of values and XSD schema. I need to make XML according to XSD with THESE specific values. XML file what I want to create is specific with correct _event_, _attribute_ names...

Comment: Also this one, what you sent me the last one, doesn't work. 
Error message: **There is no root element**

Comment: XSD schema is 100% correct cause I took it from official page

Answer (score 2):

`xsd2inst` from [Apache xmlbeans](https://xmlbeans.apache.org/download/index.html), xmlbeans-tools packages to generate and instance out of the xsd

**On Linux**

`XMLBEANS_LIB='/usr/share/java/xmlbeans/' xsd2inst test.xsd -name shiporder> test.xml`

> xsd2inst -h
>
> Generates a document based on the given Schema file
> having the given element as root.
> The tool makes reasonable attempts to create a valid document,
> but this is not always possible since, for example,
> there are schemas for which no valid instance document
> can be produced.
> Usage: xsd2inst [flags] schema.xsd -name element_name
> Flags:
> -name    the name of the root element
> -dl      enable network downloads for imports and includes
> -nopvr   disable particle valid (restriction) rule
> -noupa   disable unique particle attribution rule

**On Windows** `inst2xsd.cmd` from the same package can be used (not tested)

Comment: What if I'm using Windows? :))