# How to create XML from XSD where schema is in multiple XSDs

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I need to create an XML file from an XSD file, but its schema is present in multiple XSDs. I have tried to create using Eclipse IDE.

To generate XML for CREATEE_ABC_REQ, two other schemas are present in ABC-Messaging.xsd and EX-Bulk-Types.xsd.

Below is the CREATEE_ABC_REQ.XSD which is the root XSD.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  xmlns="http://abc.def.com/service/SOMEService" targetNamespace="http://abc.def.com/service/SOMEService" elementFormDefault="qualified">
   <xs:include schemaLocation="ABC-Messaging.xsd"/>
   <xs:include schemaLocation="EX-Bulk-Types.xsd"/>
   <xs:element name="CREATEE_ABC_REQ">
      <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="HEADER" type="HEADERType"/>
            <xs:element name="BODY">
               <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                     <xs:element name="ABC-Master-Full" type="abcblk-Full-Type"/>
                  </xs:sequence>
               </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
         </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Below is ABC-Messaging.xsd

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:complexType name="HEADERType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="SOURCE" type="SOURCEType" />
            <xs:element name="OPERATION" type="OperationType" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:simpleType name="SOURCEType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="[a-zA-Z_0-9]*" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="OperationType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="[a-zA-Z_0-9]*" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

Below is EX-Bulk-Types.xsd

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
   <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">
      </xs:documentation>
   </xs:annotation>

   <xs:complexType name="abcblk-Full-Type">
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element name="SAMPLE" minOccurs="0">
            <xs:simpleType>
               <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                  <xs:maxLength value="35"/>
               </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
         </xs:element>
         <xs:element name="SAMPLE2" minOccurs="0">
            <xs:simpleType>
               <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                  <xs:maxLength value="35"/>
               </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
         </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

How do I generate XML for this?

Comment: What have you tried, and what are you stuck on? Given the root XSD uses `include`, it should work just as if the content of the other two XSDs are in the root XSD (i.e. as if there is only one XSD).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel , I Have tried to Generate XML using Eclipse for above XSD. But while Generating, It Does not Create For two XSD which is in the  root XSD.

Comment: Then you need to edit your question and provide a [mre] that describes exactly what you do, what the results were and what you expected. Also, please don't randomly capitalize words. In English, you only capitalize the first letter of a sentence, 'I' (first person singular), and the first letter of given names (including languages, names of months and days, etc). All other words should be lowercase.

Comment: Are you constrained to use Eclipse? There are many other tools that attempt to generate XML from XSD.

Comment: Generate an XML instance with XMLBeans: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50106696/create-xml-file-according-to-xsd-schema/50106837#50106837

Comment: The includes in the schema should allow multiple schemas to be combined.  An well formed Xml has only one root element.  If you have two different xml you need to have another schema which has two possible child items.

Comment: @MichaelKay could you please suggest me some other tool for this

Comment: I've come across several (e.g. the one in Oxygen), but I don't know whether they provide the feature you require.