# how to create xml as an instance from xsd in python

Tags: python, xml, xsd

i have xsd file and my task is to create an empty xml based on that xsd i tried to use an external
package that i found on github here's the link https://github.com/fortesp/xsd2xml
and here's what i tried

```
!git clone https://github.com/fortesp/xsd2xml.git
!pip install xmlschema
cd /content/sample_data/xsd2xml/xsd2xml
from xmlgenerator import XmlGenerator
from xmldatafacet import DataFacet
xmlgenerator = XmlGenerator('/content/sample_data/file.xsd', True)
print(xmlgenerator.generate()) # Output to console
xmlgenerator.write('filename.xml') # Output to file
```

but it gaves me an error on the `xmlgenerator.generate()`
in the pacakge.
My question here is there's any other solution other than what i'm trying to do?

Comment: You probably just need to add ToString() : print(xmlgenerator.generate().ToString()) # Output to console

Comment: @jdweng not that error bec it gaves me an error inside the function itself so that i didn't share the error and asking for another approach bec this package isn't gonna work for me

Comment: I use xsd.exe to create xml classes from the schema.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/xml-schema-definition-tool-xsd-exe

Comment: using XMLBeans java utility https://stackoverflow.com/a/50106837/2834978

Comment: "but it gaves me an error" What is the error message you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

I just downloaded the code and got few errors.
You may need to change in code:
xsdnode.type.**content_type** to xsdnode.type.**content** (around two places in xmlgenerator.py)

It should work after that.