# Create an XML Document Based on an XSD Schema

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to generate sample XML documents from their DTD or XSD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106/how-to-generate-sample-xml-documents-from-their-dtd-or-xsd)

I know that visual studio 2010 can generate sample XML document from an XSD schema, but there is no documentation to show how to do that programmatically. Does anyone have hints on how to accomplish this in C#?  Thanks.

Comment: There are numerous solutions on these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106/how-to-generate-sample-xml-documents-from-their-dtd-or-xsd http://stackoverflow.com/questions/761661/tool-to-generate-xml-file-from-xsd-for-testing Several of them are open-source, so you should be able to grab the source and see exactly how they do it.