# Creating an XML file from a xsd Schema at runtime

Tags: xml, vb.net, xsd, visual-studio-2005, .net-2.0

I'm trying to create an xml report of the settings of a test.
My program is a testing suite and I would like to know the information it runs with, and present it in xml format.

I have an xml schema written in w3c saved in an xsd file. Ideally I would like to generate the xml directly from the schema, so if a change occurs in the program, only the schema needs to be changed to change the resulting report.

This involves creating the xml directly from the schema, I am really not sure how to do this, or if its even possible without tons of work.

Let me lay it out again for clarity.

I have an xsd file that is a schema. I want to use this schema to generate an xml from a function call in my program. So it takes the schema and gives me a matching xml file with the fields filled in with the values of my variables.

I hope this is clear, let me know if this is even possible.

I am in vb.net, using visual studio 2005. I think its vb version 2.0 or 2.5

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530424/generating-an-xml-file-using-xsd-file
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/761661/tool-to-generate-xml-file-from-xsd-for-testing

Answer (score 0):

You can reuse XmlSampleGenerator from [Generating XML Documents from XML Schemas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302296.aspx)

Comment: I need to try to generate it without external tools, is this possible?