# Generating XML Documents from XML Schemas in C++

Tags: c++, xml, qt, xsd

Is there any easy way to create at least a template XML file using XML Schema? My main interest is bounded by C++, but discussions of other programming languages are also welcome.By the way I also use QT framework.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307616/xml-instance-generation-from-xml-schema-xsd

Comment: Check this one... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106/how-to-generate-sample-xml-documents-from-their-dtd-or-xsd.. It has accepted answer too and lot other suggestions..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may have to write this yourself. There is no one way of getting an XML file from a Schema. If you can make domain-specific assumptions (e.g. how to populate data items, which items to choose in case of a choice, how often to insert domain-specific elements) then you will get a better instance document.

If you are working with C++, note that [Xerces C++](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/) allows you to load a schema and access its model (i.e. access it properly, not just load the schema as an XML document). I suggest you download it an check out the [SCMPrint Sample](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/scmprint-3.html). It will show you how to traverse a schema. You can then modify that to print out a sample XML file instead.

Answer (score -1):

In Qt 4.5 the XML support has been extended by an XSLT implementation, that allows you to easily convert documents from one XML dialect into another or generating source code from a XML description

[W3C XML Schema validation with Qt](http://labs.trolltech.com/blogs/2009/02/03/w3c-xml-schema-validation-with-qt/)

Example:

```
    #include <QtXmlPatterns/QXmlSchema>
    #include <QtXmlPatterns/QXmlSchemaValidator>

    QXmlSchema schema;
    schema.load( QUrl("file:///home/jordenysp/example.xsd") );

    if ( schema.isValid() ) {
        QXmlSchemaValidator validator( schema );
        if ( validator.validate( QUrl("file:///home/jordenysp/result.xml") ) ) {
            qDebug() < < "Is valid";
        } else {
            qDebug() << "Is invalid";
        }
    } else {
        qDebug() << "Is invalid";
    }
```

Comment: Your example is a validation example, not a transformation of XML.