# perl module similar to pyXSD

Tags: xml, perl

My question is similar to following

[XML instance generation from XML schema (xsd)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307616/xml-instance-generation-from-xml-schema-xsd)

I am looking for any perl Module/code which has this implementation i.e. can generate XML from XSD?

or do we have any perl package similar to Java's JAXB?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `XML::Compile`? Its [FAQ](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aCompile%3a%3aFAQ) seems promising.