# Can some one tell me how to generate a sample XML from the XSD given by the IRS for 2017

Tags: xml, xsd

I am trying to generate sample XML from the XSD given by the IRS for tax year 2017.It doesn't seem to be working.I am new to XSD/xml.Could any of you pls let me know how to generate sample XML from XSD given by IRS for 2017 year.

I tried xmlspy and other online tools,the sample gets generated without any elements.

Please find the XSD for both the manifest file and form data file in the below url - https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-schema/aca_schemapck_ty2017v1.0.zip

Below are files that I was trying to generate the xml sample for in the above Zip file.

ACA AIR-IEP Internal FS18 Upstream v0.0.5 XML Library 8.7 for UI as of 06202017\ACA AIR-IEP FS18 XML LIBRARY 8.7\EXT\IRS-EXT-ACA-AIR-1094BC.xsd

ACA AIR-IEP Internal FS18 Upstream v0.0.5 XML Library 8.7 for UI as of 06202017\ACA AIR-IEP FS18 XML LIBRARY 8.7\MSG\IRS-Form1094-1095CTransmitterUpstreamMessage.xsd

Hope this helps! Thank you !

Comment: please read [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and reformulate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XML instance generation from XML schema (xsd)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307616/xml-instance-generation-from-xml-schema-xsd)

Comment: There are lots of different tools sets that can be used to do that, so your is just about asking for a tool recommendation, which is off-topic.   If you add details of what tools you already have, what you tried to do with them, and the issue you have with them, then your question may be on topic.  Even better would be if you included the XSD as well (or at least a link as to where it is defined)