# Generating XML from XSDs

Tags: xml, xsd

I have an bunch of XSDs which in turn inherits schema's from different XSD's and I need to generate an XML file for testing purpose from this XSD. I am using the [oXygen XML Editor](http://www.oxygenxml.com/) to do this but when I try to do it, it is not working for me and it says please define root node but than it does not allow me to do so. So if anyone had worked with oxygenXML do suggest of what could be way around for this ?

Additional Question: How can we validate incoming XML file with XSD's which inherits schema's from other XSD's ? here the things is that I have single incoming XML file where as I have around 57 XSD's some of which inherits schema's from other XSD's.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [XMLSPY](http://www.altova.com/download/xmlspy/xml_editor_standard.html). Using XMLSPY you can generate XSD/DTD from XML or generate simple XML (without values) from XSD and validate the XML with XSD.

Comment: XMLSpy (release 10) has the following drawback: If you have more than one root in your XSD you have to generate for each root separately.

Answer (score 1):

Since oXygen is commercial software, why not ask [on their forum](http://www.oxygenxml.com/forum/) or just [contact them for support](http://www.oxygenxml.com/contact.html)?

Comment: Or try one of these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428359/generate-xml-from-xsd :)

Answer (score 0):

once more suggestion is if you have BizTalk installed on your machine. The Visual studio support for XSD is excellent. You can right click on a XSD and generate instance will generate an XML for you.

You can also try using this tool from Microsoft

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302296.aspx

Comment: Or post your XSD we can generate the XML for you.

Comment: I have detailed outline of my XSD's on this question and further clarification of what am actually trying to achieve...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614015/working-with-multiple-xsds