# How do you validate XML with portion of XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd

How do you validate XML with only a portion of XSD ?

Comment: Can you check this question too, it describes underlying scenario more clearly, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614015/working-with-multiple-xsds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can - you need to validate your XML against a complete XML schema. If you have several that are made up of various imports, you need one XSD file for each of those various "partial" subsets.

Marc

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate a bit on the issue?

As a stab in the dark, I would say that as long as the xsd is well formed should be able to run the xml against it; that said there is no assurance that it will validate. Can you post the xml and/or the xsd fragment?

Comment: Can you go through this question...I have described completely my scenario over there...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614015/working-with-multiple-xsds