# Use Netbeans to Create Sample XML from XSD

Tags: xml, netbeans, xsd

How do you use Netbeans to generate a sample XML file from an XSD? I see that this question has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428359/generate-xml-from-xsd) and it would appear that it can be done. Though, there are [some reports](http://www.narendranaidu.com/2010/04/xsd-to-xml-and-vice-versa.html) that make it seem it cannot.

What menu or window is the option located under? I have looked under every menu as well as searched the plugins. My version of Netbeans: **NetBeans IDE 7.0.1 (Build 201107282000)**

Answer (score 32, accepted):

From a project that contains the `.xsd`:

1. Click `New File` on the tool bar or `File > New File` from the menu
2. Choose `XML > XML Document`
3. Name your file, click next
4. Choose `XML Schema-Constrained Document`, click next
5. Click the `Browse` button and use `By File` to navigate to the `.xsd`
6. Click the `Import` check box beside the file name, click next
7. Review the options available and click `Finish` to generate

You can use more than one `.xsd` file to generate the `.xml`.  In this case it will use whichever `.xsd` file you choose as `Primary` to resolve any conflicts.