# How to activate Fluid (TYPO3) autocompletion in Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, autocomplete, typo3, fluid, typo3-6.2.x

I did what it said here: [Extbase and Fluid Autocompletion](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/1-Installation/4-extbase-and-fluid-autocompletion.html)

> In NetBeans right-click your Extension project and choose Properties
>   in the opened context menu to edit the project properties. Select the
>   category *PHP Include Path* and use *Add Folder...* to add the directories
>   of Extbase and Fluid.

So I added the Fluid and Extbase Folders which I previously copied onto my computer from the Server at */var/www/typo3_src/typo3_src-6.2.25/typo3/sysext*:

[image]

but it didn't work - here's my Project:

[image]

And here is fluid stuff that the editor still doesn't recognize:

[image]

What am I doing or thinking wrong?

Comment: Adding the folder to the PHP include paths only helps the autocompletion in PHP, not in fluid templates. For that, you have to import the XML schemas for fluid and any extensions you use. [Here](https://fluidtypo3.org/documentation/templating-manual/appendix/fluid-autocompletion.html) is some info on how to generate and use those (for PhpStorm, but the same thing could work for netbeans).

Comment: I can't really figure it out for Netbeans :(

Comment: http://netbeans-org.1045718.n5.nabble.com/Schemas-for-code-completion-with-xsd-tt5752294.html#none

+ take files from https://fluidtypo3.org/schemas/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found info here, works for me:

> It's an old topic but I have a trick so that you can add Auto-complete
> function for fluid, vhs, flux.
>
> First of all, download the XSD schema files from here :
> https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/fluid/master.html put them
> somewhere locally.
>
> Next step, in Netbeans, go to menu Tools > DTD and XML Schemas, add
> your 3 DTD in user catalog :
>
> Flux : Public ID = http://typo3.org/ns/FluidTYPO3/Flux/ViewHelpers URI
> = path to your flux XDS file
>
> Fluid : Public ID = http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/Fluid/ViewHelpers URI =
> path to your fluid XDS file
>
> Vhs : Public ID = http://typo3.org/ns/FluidTYPO3/Vhs/ViewHelpers URI =
> path to your flux VHS file
>
> Next, in project properties, go to 'testing' menu and add the folder
> where you stored your DTD.
>
> Now, in your Project > Test Files, add a new XML Document and choose
> "XML Schema-Constrained Document" on next step, click the button
> 'Browse' and By File > Your Project > Test Files and select import for
> all the xsd schema files.
>
> Then, change the prefix f for fluid, flux for flux and vhs for vhs
> choose fluid as primary and finish.
>
> A file is created with this content :
> And into the section <f:alias>, you have the auto-completion for
> fluid, vhs and flux.

```
<f:alias
        xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
        xmlns:f='http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/Fluid/ViewHelpers'
        xmlns:vhs='http://typo3.org/ns/FluidTYPO3/Vhs/ViewHelpers'
        xmlns:flux='http://typo3.org/ns/FluidTYPO3/Flux/ViewHelpers'
        xsi:schemaLocation='http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/Fluid/ViewHelpers file:/home/florian/Documents/Docs/Netbeans/Autocomplete%20Fluid/Schemas/Fluid.xsd
   http://typo3.org/ns/FluidTYPO3/Vhs/ViewHelpers file:/home/florian/Documents/Docs/Netbeans/Autocomplete%20Fluid/Schemas/Vhs.xsd
   http://typo3.org/ns/FluidTYPO3/Flux/ViewHelpers file:/home/florian/Documents/Docs/Netbeans/Autocomplete%20Fluid/Schemas/Flux.xsd'>
   
        Auto-completion here
       
</f:alias>
```

http://netbeans-org.1045718.n5.nabble.com/Schemas-for-code-completion-with-xsd-tt5752294.html#none

- take files from https://fluidtypo3.org/schemas/

Some more info [Use Netbeans to Create Sample XML from XSD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811715/use-netbeans-to-create-sample-xml-from-xsd/7816248)

From a project that contains the `.xsd`:

1. Click `New File` on the tool bar or `File > New File` from the menu
2. Choose `XML > XML Document`
3. Name your file, click next
4. Choose `XML Schema-Constrained Document`, click next
5. Click the `Browse` button and use `By File` to navigate to the `.xsd`
6. Click the `Import` check box beside the file name, click next
7. Review the options available and click `Finish` to generate

You can use more than one `.xsd` file to generate the `.xml`.  In this case it will use whichever `.xsd` file you choose as `Primary` to resolve any conflicts.

Comment: I don't use Netbeans anymore so I won't be able to verify this, but I trust you - so I accept the answer ;)

Comment: Hm... I was need you test first if it's work as you expected.  For me still no suggestion (like arguments or other) but no more warnings and Formatting works fine event for single tags like <f:translate/>. Plus I just collect this from other guys' answers. SO not sure if i earn this :)