# Can anyone provide me with a NHibernate mapping (hbm) file that contains full range of xml elements used in NHibernate?

Tags: xml, nhibernate, hbm

Can anyone provide me with a NHibernate mapping (hbm) file that contains a full range of xml elements?

I need a complete mapping file to get an idea of how many xml elements are there in use in NHibernate mapping files and how to place them and how to use them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you download the [latest builds](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhibernate/files) there are two XSD schemas in the `Required_Bins` folder. Simply copy these files into:-

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Xml\Schemas
```

or

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Xml\Schemas
```

[image: files]

This will give you IntelliSense within Visual Studio.

To get a XML document from an XSD schema see this [S.O. post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428359/generate-xml-from-xsd).