# XML generation tool

Tags: xml, xsd

Can any one show me some online tool or any other free tool which can produce a XML file based on my XSD with some dummy data.

i have a XSD with lots of fields and i don't want to do it manualy so looking some auto tool who can help me so that i can focus on parsing part rather than XML creation

Comment: What tool did you use to create the XSD? Many of these tools come with "create sample XML" features, but they are not always well known. I think even Eclipse has this ability somewhere in it.

Comment: Potential duplicate...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106/how-to-generate-sample-xml-documents-from-their-dtd-or-xsd

Comment: i have use JAXB 2.x for xsd creation,all i want a xml with some dummy data based on the XSD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there's an online tool for this.

However take a look at [this discussion](http://lists.xml.org/archives/xml-dev/200402/msg00309.html).

Anyway Eclipse IDE can generate an XML file starting from a XML Schema or a DTD or an XML template.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Altova XML Spy](http://www.altova.com). It will generate sample XML based on a schema file. The sample data will only be default text based on the data type of the elements (i.e. xs:string elements are populated with the word 'String', xs:int elements are populated with 0, etc...).

XMLSpy is only free as a trial, but if you're working with a lot of XML it's definitely a worthwhile investment.

Comment: i was about there download page.thaks

Answer (score 0):

The [OpenXSD](http://www.k-int.com/products/OpenXSD) library mentions that they have support for generating XML instances based on the XSD. Check that out.