# How do you open XML Schema Explorer

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2008, xsd

I have an XSD file from which I want to create sample XML.

I found [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106/how-to-generate-sample-xml-documents-from-their-dtd-or-xsd/41821#41821) that tells me to use XML Schema Explorer.

But when I open my XSD file in Visual Studio 2008 SP1, I cannot find the option to open the XML Schema Explorer as outlined.

How do I open this window?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it as follows:

I created a new file of type 'XML Schema'. That opened up the XML Schema Explorer. Then I switched to my file and the XML Schema Explorer window stayed open.

---

Comment: imgur.com/NykiFXd i was not able to find this option

Answer (score 5):

In VS2010:

1. Right click on your existing `.xsd` file and select "**open with**".
2. Select "**XML Schema Designer**"
3. Then in the template that comes up, click the link that says "**XML Schema Explorer**".

Comment: Note: the XML Schem Explorer will automatcially close if the file it's referencing closes.

Comment: imgur.com/NykiFXd i was not able to find this option

Answer (score 0):

From [How do you open XML Schema Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737308/how-do-you-open-xml-schema-explorer):

The XML Schema Explorer provides a hierarchal view of the schema set through a tree view.     The XML Schema Explorer also provides search, filtering, navigation, and sorting. To access the XML Schema Explorer, do one of the following:

- If you are on the Start View, click the XML Schema Explorer link.
- If you are on the Graph View or the Content Model View and have nodes
  in your workspace, use the context menu to select the XML Schema
  Explorer.
- You can also select the XML Schema Explorerfrom the View menu.
- You can access the XML Schema Explorerfrom a .vb file that has a
  Visual Basic XML literal associated with an .xsd file. To see the
  schema set in the XML Schema Explorer, right click an XML node in an
  XML literal or an XML namespace import and select the Show in Schema
  Explorer command. For more information, see Integration of XML
  Literals with XML Schema Explorer.

Drag the xsd into Visual Studio and then it will be under the View menu.

Comment: Your post overflows the stack ;)

Answer (score 0):

This question and the various answers helped me investigate how to open XSD files in the XML Designer for Visual Studio 2017 (Community Edition).  I used the method to create an XSD in an existing project, which confirmed that the XML Designer and XML Schema Explorer were available.  Then I went to `File>Open>File...` and entered the URL of the public XSD I wanted to see.  Both the XML Designer and XML Schema Explorer then popped up with the content of the public XSD.