# XMLVend Example XML Request and Response?

Tags: php, xml, xsd, xmlvend

### Environment

- Ubuntu 11.04 x64
- PHP 5.3.5
- VIM 7.3.35
- [XMLVend Specification](http://nrs.eskom.co.za/xmlvend/docs/default.asp)

I am writing an XMLVend API and I would like to have some example XML generated from some of the specification files I have access to.  So my question is as follows:

How can I go about deriving/generating valid XML files from the WSDL, XSL, XSD, and JSPX files I have access too?

### Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Found this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106/how-to-generate-sample-xml-documents-from-their-dtd-or-xsd/28121#28121) from user [levand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3044/levand) who recommended [Oxygen](http://www.oxygenxml.com/).  Using their 30 day free trial I was able to generate some example XML documents of the different types I needed.

Specifically, after installing and launching Oxygen XML Editor, I went to Tools > Generate Sample XML Files, picked my .xsd file, and then selected my root element (or type of XML file to generate if your .xsd defines multiple types like different types of requests or responses).