# How can i generate sample XML from DTD?

Tags: java, xml, dtd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to generate sample XML documents from their DTD or XSD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106/how-to-generate-sample-xml-documents-from-their-dtd-or-xsd)

Please let me know if there is way in java to generate sample XML from DTD.

Comment: I don't see how this proposed duplicate answers this question, especially since the OP requests a Java solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Generating sample XML from XSD or DTD in Eclipse](http://www.twm-kd.com/programming-computers/generating-sample-xml-from-xsd-or-dtd-in-eclipse/)