# XML validation against XSD: The element xxx has invalid child element yyy in namespace zzz

Tags: xml, xsd

The XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:DataBodyTemperature="Docobo.DataBodyTemperature" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:complexType name="tDataBodyTemperature">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Answer" type="xs:double" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="AmbientTemperature" type="xs:double" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="tDataItem">
      <xs:choice>
        <xs:element name="DataBodyTemperature" type="tDataBodyTemperature" />
      </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="DataItem">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:complexContent mixed="false">
        <xs:extension base="tDataItem">
          <xs:attribute fixed="1" name="SchemaVersion" type="xs:integer" />
        </xs:extension>
      </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The XML:

```
<DataItem>
  <DataBodyTemperature xmlns:DataBodyTemperature="Docobo.DataBodyTemperature">
    <DataBodyTemperature:Answer>37.8</DataBodyTemperature:Answer>
    <DataBodyTemperature:AmbientTemperature>28.5</DataBodyTemperature:AmbientTemperature>
  </DataBodyTemperature >
</DataItem>
```

I am getting a validation error:
*Xml failed schema validation: The element 'DataBodyTemperature' has invalid child element 'Answer' in namespace 'Docobo.DataBodyTemperature'. List of possible elements expected: 'Answer'*

Comment: The error message doesn't match your XML - there *is* no element named  `DataBodyTemperature` in that XML.

Comment: @skaffman: Sorry that was a mistake I have corrected the XML now and it has a body temperature element but I think there is some namespace issue which causes this error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that your schema doesn't specify a target namespace - consequently all types are associated with the null namespace.

Your error is caused because the schema specifies that the `DataBodyTemperature` element (which is in the null namespace) should contain only `Answer` and `AmbientTemperature` elements (both of which are declared in the null namespace), however in your document these elements are in fact in the `Docobo.DataBodyTemperature` namespace, essentially making them completely different elements.

A sample of xml conforming to your given schema would be:

```
<DataItem SchemaVersion="1">
  <DataBodyTemperature>
    <Answer>1</Answer>
    <AmbientTemperature>1</AmbientTemperature>
  </DataBodyTemperature>
</DataItem>
```

Notice that there is no namespace declaration - all elements are in the default namespace.  I suspect what you really want however is to modify your xsd so that it specifies a target namespace.

```
<xs:schema targetNamespace="Docobo.DataBodyTemperature" xmlns:dbt="Docobo.DataBodyTemperature" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:complexType name="tDataBodyTemperature">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Answer" type="xs:double" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="AmbientTemperature" type="xs:double" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="tDataItem">
    <xs:choice>
      <xs:element name="DataBodyTemperature" type="dbt:tDataBodyTemperature" />
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="DataItem">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:complexContent mixed="false">
        <xs:extension base="dbt:tDataItem">
          <xs:attribute fixed="1" name="SchemaVersion" type="xs:integer" />
        </xs:extension>
      </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Note that you now also need to qualify the `tDataItem` and `tDataBodyTemperature` types as they are no longer declared in the null namespace.

Also note that in your sameple XML the `DataItem` and `DataBodyTemperature` elements aren't in the "Docobo.DataBodyTemperature" namespace and so now wouldn't be validated against the above schema.

You may also find it helpeful to get a sample xml document for a schema - you can do this in Visual Studio 2008 or later using the XML Schema Explorer, see [How to generate sample XML documents from their DTD or XSD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106/how-to-generate-sample-xml-documents-from-their-dtd-or-xsd).

Comment: No the schema specifies a DataItem element of type tDataItem and the tDataItem has a choice of elements (currently only DataBodyTemperature). The DataBodyTemperature is of type tDataBodyTemperature which then contains 2 elements; The answer and AmbientTemperature

Comment: @Shahid Ah - you updated your question, I've now fixed my answer.

Comment: Thank you justin. I put just one choice  'DataBodyTemperature' here but I have many other choices all with different namespace qualifiers. Can we use multiple target namespaces. Is it possible to only qualify the tDataBodyTemperature with a namespace and leave any other elements with the null namespace

Comment: @Shahid Yes you can use multiple target namespaces, however to my knowledge you would need a different XSD schema document for each namespace, for example one document which describes all elements in the null namespace and another describing all elements in the `Docobo.DataBodyTemperature` namespace.