# Stop xsd.exe from generating multidimensional arrays

Tags: xml, arrays, serialization, xsd, schema

I have XSD Schema with the following structure:
`ElementA` has only one `ElementB` and that has zero to infinite of `ElementC`

```
ElementA -> ElementB -> ElementC[]
```

When I generate classes with this schema and `xsd.exe` it generates multidimensional arrays: Everywhere `ElementA` is used it puts `ElementC[][][]`. For each depth one dimension. Is there way to stop `xsd.exe` doing this?

For example the XSD defines an element called `carList` that contains only the car-tags (zero to infinite "car"). The `xsd.exe` should then create a class called `carList` that contains only an one-dimensional array or an list of car. Instead wherever a `carList` would be used it puts an `car[][]`. Don't like that.

One more question, is there a way to generate a XML that fits an given XSD besides generating classes that will be filled and serialized?

Comment: [How to generate sample XML documents from their DTD or XSD?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106/how-to-generate-sample-xml-documents-from-their-dtd-or-xsd)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use xsd.exe as well and I don't know a better way, at least for .NET platform.

After generating XSD schema file from XML, you need to modify the dimension ranges in XSD file then generate the Class. Because, dimensions in XML are unclear. You may have a single node at the moment but maybe you can add more in the future. Rules are not certain. Because of that reason, you need to edit XSD manually before generating the code files.