# Batch generating sample xml for loads for XSD files

Tags: c#, java, c++, xml, xsd

I need to generate sample xml from xsd for testing prupose and XMLSpy does the job nicely !

But I don't want to do it one by one, I want to be able to do it in batch as I have loads for XSD files also whenever I made some changes to those XSD files,  I want to be able to easily generate xml from XSD files again.

Is there any API there for this job ? C++, C#, java, python I don't care as long as it works.

Or is there any easy way of doing it ?

BTW I know I can use xsd tool to generate c# class then write a few line of c# code to provide some data to generate xml, but this way I need to provide data for each XSD which I really don't want to ...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the xsd2inst command from the open-source Java project [XMLBeans](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/)

Usage is [here](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/guide/tools.html#xsd2inst).

Also check out this: [How to generate sample XML documents from their DTD or XSD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106/how-to-generate-sample-xml-documents-from-their-dtd-or-xsd/)