# Serialize object to XML based on existing XSD schema

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xml-serialization, xsd-validation

I have to create an XML document that would be based on an certain XML Schema Document. Since my data is a `DataSet`, I need to find the best way to start off.

I have couple of different ideas how to start:

- manually create nodes, elements, attributes that would match XSD
- transform `DataSet` into a class that would match the schema document and serialize it
- something else?

Is this a right way to get a XML output from `DataSet` to match XSD schema?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to generate sample XML documents from their DTD or XSD?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106/how-to-generate-sample-xml-documents-from-their-dtd-or-xsd)

Comment: Where exactly are you starting from? Would using an xsd2java tool be useful?

Comment: @DonalFellows Well I am trying to figure out what would be the best way to start... I have data as a DataSet in c#.

Answer (score 1):

May be you should give XMLBeans a try... It's a diverse framework for playing around with compiled XSD schemas. Compiled in this context means, you create JAVA classes from your XSD-files.

Compilation example (as can be seen [here](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/index.html#Getting+Started)) `scomp -out purchaseorder.jar purchaseorder.xsd`

With this jar in your classpath you could create new a priori valid instances of your schema with something like:

```
public PurchaseOrderDocument createPO() {
    PurchaseOrderDocument newPODoc = PurchaseOrderDocument.Factory.newInstance();
    PurchaseOrder newPO = newPODoc.addNewPurchaseOrder();
    Customer newCustomer = newPO.addNewCustomer();
    newCustomer.setName("Doris Kravitz");
    newCustomer.setAddress("Bellflower, CA");
    return newPODoc;
}
```

You can find the whole example at: [XMLBeans Tutorial](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/guide/conGettingStartedwithXMLBeans.html) under the heading "Creating New XML Instances from Schema".