# How can I generate Junit XML output from a Perl script?

Tags: junit, jenkins, hudson, bamboo

I'm setting up System Verilog regressions using Bamboo, and we're using Perl for our scripting environment.  We're already using XML::Simple for some other stuff, but I'm not extremely familiar with XML terminology beyond the basics.

I've got a script that submits a bunch of compile jobs and run jobs to SGE, and the tests run and complete.  I need another script that parses through the results in each run directory, and I'd like to get as much info into the XML results file as possible, beyond just pass/fail.  In places I've seen this used before, we had compile time, run times, what machines it ran on, and lots of other info reported.

I'm having trouble figuring out the XML reporting format for Bamboo.  Most of what I've found on google seems to assume your language automatically generates it.  I've found an XSD schema, but that's a little beyond me.

Is there a clear spec that describes the valid fields and how to use them?  Or do I just need to suck it up and hand-parse the schema?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, an XSD is probably the best you can get, as the format is explicitly and unambiguously defined there. Have a look at this cool tutorial at w3schools: http://www.w3schools.com/schema/ . XSD is not that bad.

Another option you might try, if XSD seems to much, are tools that generate sample XML documents based on XSD. Check this Stack Overflow: question [How to generate sample XML documents from their DTD or XSD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106/how-to-generate-sample-xml-documents-from-their-dtd-or-xsd) It has been closed as "not constructive" , but the answers might help.