# How to Generate an XML out of XSD in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I tried lot of online tools to generate xml out of complex xsd file but things are not working. Is there any possibility to generate an xml out of complex xsd file in Groovy or any other third party applications to covert xsd into xml

Comment: Do you mean to generate sample xml documents that satisfy the requirements of your xsd, or are you looking for groovy object bindings to an xsd that will generate compliant xml?

Comment: I am looking for xml document that satifies the requirements of my xsd

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106/how-to-generate-sample-xml-documents-from-their-dtd-or-xsd