# Generate XML from schema

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I have a large XSD file and I must build a valid XML.
The problem is that I don't have a demo XML, and I'm new to XML so I would like to know if it's possible to generate a sample file with random data according to the specifications.

If you know a tool, a tutorial or something that could help me to start in the right way...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to generate sample XML documents from their DTD or XSD?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106/how-to-generate-sample-xml-documents-from-their-dtd-or-xsd)

Comment: Hmm, there is an interesting answer about Eclipse in this thread, I will take a look

Comment: Eclipse has totally failed. I tested every solution in this thread and only one has worked, but has worked exactly how I wanted : Intellij Idea. Thanks. Do you think I should close this thread ?

Comment: I would.  It's a duplicate of an offtopic thread.  It's likely to be closed as such.

Answer (score 0):

Some XML tools can do this, for example [XmlSeed](http://www.xmlseed.com/).