# Using Java to generate xml from an XSD schema

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I have a requirement to create a sort of 'skeleton' xml based on an XSD schema.

The documents defined by these schemas have no namespace. They are authored by other developers, not in an automated way.

There is no mixed content allowed.  That is, elements can contain elements only, or text only.

The rules for this sample xml are:

- elements that can contain only text content should not be created in the   sample xml
- all other optional and mandatory elements should be included in the sample xml
- elements should be created only once even if they can occur multiple times
- any other nodes such as attributes, comments, processing instruction, etc. should be ommited - the sample xml would be an 'element tree'

Are there APIs or tools in Java that can generate such sample xml?  I'm looking for pointers where to get started.

This needs to be done programmatically in a reliable way, as the sample xml is used by other XSLT transformations.

Answer (score 4):

Hope below code will serve your purpose

```
    package com.example.demo;
    import java.io.File;

    import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
    import javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException;
    import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

    import org.w3c.dom.Document;
    import org.w3c.dom.Element;

    import jlibs.xml.sax.XMLDocument;
    import jlibs.xml.xsd.XSInstance;
    import jlibs.xml.xsd.XSParser;

    public interface xsdtoxml {
         public static void main(String[] pArgs) {
                try {
                    String filename = "out.xsd";
                    // instance.

                    final Document doc = loadXsdDocument(filename);

                    //Find the docs root element and use it to find the targetNamespace
                    final Element rootElem = doc.getDocumentElement();
                    String targetNamespace = null;
                    if (rootElem != null && rootElem.getNodeName().equals("xs:schema")) 
                               {
                        targetNamespace = rootElem.getAttribute("targetNamespace");
                    }


                    //Parse the file into an XSModel object
                    org.apache.xerces.xs.XSModel xsModel = new XSParser().parse(filename);

                    //Define defaults for the XML generation
                    XSInstance instance = new XSInstance();
                    instance.minimumElementsGenerated = 1;
                    instance.maximumElementsGenerated = 1;
                    instance.generateDefaultAttributes = true;
                    instance.generateOptionalAttributes = true;
                    instance.maximumRecursionDepth = 0;
                    instance.generateAllChoices = true;
                    instance.showContentModel = true;
                    instance.generateOptionalElements = true;

                    //Build the sample xml doc
                    //Replace first param to XMLDoc with a file input stream to write to file
                    QName rootElement = new QName(targetNamespace, "out");
                    XMLDocument sampleXml = new XMLDocument(new StreamResult(System.out), true, 4, null);
                    instance.generate(xsModel, rootElement, sampleXml);
                } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) 
                        {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            public static Document loadXsdDocument(String inputName) {
                final String filename = inputName;

                final DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                        .newInstance();
                factory.setValidating(false);
                factory.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);
                factory.setIgnoringComments(true);
                Document doc = null;

                try {
                    final DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
                    final File inputFile = new File(filename);
                    doc = builder.parse(inputFile);
                } catch (final Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    // throw new ContentLoadException(msg);
                }

                return doc;
            }

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

xsd to xml :

1 : you can use eclipse (right click and select Generate)

2 : Sun/Oracle Multi-Schema Validator

3 : xmlgen

see: 
[How to generate sample XML documents from their DTD or XSD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106/how-to-generate-sample-xml-documents-from-their-dtd-or-xsd)

for subtle requirements, you should program it yourself

Comment: Not sure why this was -1'd, the link pretty much covers all the options. I think you will have to take an existing solution and modify it for your needs, but many of the suggestions are a good starting point.

Comment: The question is asking how to generate XML sample from XSD using JAVA programming, not a tool.