Generate fake data into xml files based on xsd
I have an XSD file with a complex structure that is challenging to read directly. Using the JAXB-2 Maven plugin, I've generated POJO classes from this XSD. Now, I need to create a Java application that can generate fake data based on the restrictions and conditions specified in the XSD.
What would be the best approach to achieve this? How can I ensure that the generated data adheres to the constraints and conditions defined in the XSD schema?
iam looking for an approach to follow , don't want to set the attributes manually using the java data faker

Try doing it the other way around. Fake POJOs then serialise as xml. Then you have your xml

Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106/how-to-generate-sample-xml-documents-from-their-dtd-or-xsd

@queeg , no it dosent i am not looking for a tool , i need steps to follow for java application , a method that help me generate fake data based on restrictions and conditions specified in the xsd

here there's an approach using apache xmlbeans
